# How to calculate blocks of free time using start and end time?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have a Ruby on Rails application that uses MySQL and I need to calculate blocks of free (available) time given a table that has rows of start and end datetimes. This needs to be done for a range of dates, so for example, I would need to look for which times are free between May 1 and May 7. I can query the table with the times that are NOT available and use that to remove periods of time between May 1 and May 7. Times in the database are stored at a fidelity of 15 minutes on the quarter hour, meaning all times end at 00, 15, 30 or 45 minutes. There is never a time like 11:16 or 10:01, so no rounding is necessary.

I've thought about creating a hash that has time represented in 15 minute increments and defaulting all of the values to "available" (1), then iterating over an ordered resultset of rows and flipping the values in the hash to 0 for the times that come back from the database. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this, and I'm a little concerned about the memory utilization and computational intensity of that approach. This calculation won't happen all the time, but it needs to scale to happening at least a couple hundred times a day. It seems like I would also need to reprocess the entire hash to find the blocks of time that are free after this which seems pretty inefficient.

Any ideas on a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that I don't necessarily need a Ruby or RoR specific solution - any language or general algorithmic approach to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too vague. If you have the start-end unavailable time pair 11:01-11:16, do you want to round that to the nearest 15 minute point like 11:00-11:15, or you consider that every 15 minute segment of time that includes unavailable time is unavailable, so the whole 11:00-11:30 becomes unavailable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this a couple of ways.  First, my assumption is that your table shows appointments, and now you want to get a list of un-booked time, right?

So, the first way I did this was like yours, just a hash of unused times.  It's slow and limited and a little wasteful, since I have to re-calculate the hash every time someone needs to know the times that are available.

The next way I did this was borrow an idea from the data warehouse people.  I build an attribute table of all time slots that I'm interested in.  If you build this kind of table, you may want to put more information in there besides the slot times.  You may also include things like whether it's a weekend, which hour of the day it's in, whether it's during regular business hours, whether it's on a holiday, that sort of thing.  Then, I have to do a join of all slots between my start and end times and my appointments are null.  So, this is a LEFT JOIN, something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM slots 
WHERE ... 
  LEFT JOIN appointments 
    WHERE appointments.id IS NULL
```

That keeps me from having to re-create the hash every time, and it's using the database to do the set operations, something the database is optimized to do.

Also, if you make your slots table a little rich, you can start doing all sorts of queries about not only the available slots you may be after, but also on the kinds of times that tend to get booked, or the kinds of times that tend to always be available, or other interesting questions you might want to answer some day.  At the very least, you should keep track of the fields that tell you whether a slot should be one that is being filled or not (like for business hours).

Comment: Thanks David, I really like the database idea. I have one wrinkle that I didn't mention in my question that may make this approach a little more difficult and I'm curious on your thoughts... You are correct that my table has appointments and that I now want to find unbooked time. The wrinkle is that some appointments are recurring (on various schedules - daily/weekly/monthly) and recurring appointments have only 1 row in the database with an indicator of their recurrence schedule. Do you think it would be worth extrapolating the recurring events into a temp table and doing a join?

Comment: What I've done with recurring appointments is build out a permanent structure for them.  This way I could have more complicated recurrence patterns, a collection of recurrence records.  One problem I never solved satisfactorily was extrapolating this data.  The best I came up with was extracting the recurring events in a small time period like what you're thinking about.  Today, I wonder about this solution.  At some point, the complexity says we embrace this as a warehousing problem and use JRuby and mondrian-olap instead. Maybe that's the fallback when recurrence slows things down too much.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a flag in the row that indicates this. As time is allocated, flip the flag for every date/time in the appropriate range. For example May 2, 12pm to 1pm, would be marked as not available.

Then it's a simple matter of querying the date range for every row that has the availability flagged set as true.